# Question about linear mapping between two vector spaces over different fields

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, linear-transformations

I was thinking about the following problem

$V$ is a vector space over a field $K$ and $E$ is a vector space over a field $F$. Is it possible to define a linear mapping from $V$ to $E$ ?

I was thinking about this because I wanted to show that a linear application verifies the following property:

$L(0_{V})=0_{E}$

but I was stuck since I didn't have more information about the fields considered on the starting and ending vector space.

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649344/linear-transformations-between-vector-spaces-over-different-fields

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748905/can-you-define-linear-maps-between-vector-spaces-over-different-fields