# Isomorphic finite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Theorem: Two finite-dimensional vector spaces over $F$ are isomorphic if and only if
they have the same dimension.

$F$ denotes either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$

Below is proof of the theorem. Where in the proof do we assume that the vector spaces are over $F$? It seems to me like that assumption is not used. Can the theorem be restated as: "Two finite-dimensional vector spaces over the same field are isomorphic if and only if
they have the same dimension"?

[image: Proof of theorem:]

Comment: Exactly, this works over any field

Comment: Some authors unnecessarily limit the field to be either the reals or the complex numbers.

Comment: Does it not really make sense to talk about two vector spaces being isomorphic when each vector space is over a different field? Like if vector space one is over field A and vector space two if over field B, this theorem and related theorems don't really apply?

Comment: Yes Jenny, it does not make sense for vector spaces over two different fields. Btw, I find it ugly to use the [rank–nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) in the first part of the proof. Better say that an isomorphism $V\to W$ sends any basis of $V$ to a basis of $W$.

Comment: @jenny9 see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192347/mapping-vector-spaces-over-two-different-fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On page $10$ of the book the author states that you can think of $F$ denoting arbitrary fields throughout chapter $1,2$ and $3$.

[image]

Comment: Woah, how did you find the book?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose I am also currently learning from this book and I remember reading this in the beginning so I just took a screenshot from an [abridged version](https://linear.axler.net/LinearAbridged.pdf) of the book available on the author's website.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments,
the assumption of the two vector spaces $V,W$ being defined over the same field $F$, whatever is $F$, is actually relevant. In fact, when we say

```
there is a linear mapping $T:V\to W$ then bla, bla, bla...
```

this is meaningful only if $V$ and $W$ are built over the same field of scalars.